# using readXML into a JCO.table after the XML was created using JCO

Tags: java, xml, jconnect

I created a JCO.table and transformed it into XML using myTable.writeXML (JCO method)
now I'm trying to re-load the XML into a JCO.table and work with the table created from the XML.

I tried to use myNewTable.readXML (another JCO method) but I need to create an instance to my new table before and I suspect it is created empty and the XML doesn't fill it up.

any suggestions?

thanks!!!
:)

Answer (score 0):

Working with JCo 2.x?
A rather simply (hopefully not too simply) solution:

```
Table myNewTable=Table.readXML("theXML.xml");
```

Or could you already solve the problem? Could you remind, where your suspicion comes from?